# I have a Java method that returns either 0 or 1. Can I make it return a boolean without generating a branch instruction?

Tags: java, bytecode, jit

At the byte code level a Java boolean is represented as either 0 or 1.  I have an expression that results in 0 or 1 but it is computed with the int type.  A simple example would be:

```
public static int isOdd_A(int value) {
    return value & 1;
}

public static boolean isOdd_B(int value) {
    return (value & 1) == 1;
}
```

The byte code for the above methods looks like this:

```
  public static int isOdd_A(int);
    descriptor: (I)I
    Code:
       0: iload_0
       1: iconst_1
       2: iand
       3: ireturn

  public static boolean isOdd_B(int);
    descriptor: (I)Z
    Code:
       0: iload_0
       1: iconst_1
       2: iand
       3: iconst_1
       4: if_icmpne     11
       7: iconst_1
       8: goto          12
      11: iconst_0
      12: ireturn
```

The method that returns a boolean is much larger and contains a branch so it is less optimal if the machine code that runs is equivalent.

Will the HotSpot JVM know that the boolean version can be optimized to branchless machine code?  Is there a way to trick Java into using the int-based byte code for a method that returns a boolean (e.g. using ASM) ?

EDIT:
Many have suggested this isn't worth worrying about, and in general I agree. However I did created this micro benchmark and ran it with jmh and noticed an improvement with the int version of around 10%:

```
@Benchmark
public int countOddA() {
    int odds = 0;
    for (int n : numbers)
        if (Test.isOdd_A(n) == 1)
            odds++;
    return odds;
}
@Benchmark
public int countOddB() {
    int odds = 0;
    for (int n : numbers)
        if(Test.isOdd_B(n))
            odds++;
    return odds;
}

Benchmark                Mode  Cnt      Score    Error  Units
OddBenchmark.countOddA  thrpt  100  18393.818 ± 83.992  ops/s
OddBenchmark.countOddB  thrpt  100  16689.038 ± 90.182  ops/s
```

I agree the code should be readable (that's why I want the performance of the branchless int version with the proper boolean interface), and most of the time this level of optimization is not warranted. However in this case there was a 10% gain even when the method in question doesn't even account for a majority of the code.

So perhaps what we have here is a case where HotSpot can be made aware of this pattern and generate better code.

Comment: What happens if instead of `== 1` you `!!(value & 1)`?

Comment: Try this . boolean  b = (value != 0);

Comment: @Mox: looks like a compile-time error to me.

Comment: Have you make measurements and proven that the second version caused a performance problem that is fixed by using the first version? If not, don't worry about performance. It should return a boolean, not an integer. So, make your code clean and readable, and everything will be fine. I really really doubt such a trivial method could cause a performance problem, ever.

Comment: It seems to me that you're thinking in the assembler way - these times are gone forever. We doesn't need Java, .NET, Python - we CAN program directly in the processor... But, should we?

Comment: I don't see the reason for this.  Even if the method returns 1 or 0, you'll most likely end up checking *if* the method returned 1 or 0... using a branch.

Comment: You can always use a table: `static boolean[] tt = {false, true}; ... return tt[value & 1];`. But I agree that you are unlikely to need this kind of micro-optimization.

Comment: I would actually be very surprised if the HotSpot JIT peephole optimizer *didn't* use a branchless operation, especially if it detected that this was a hot code path. More importantly, the HotSpot JIT can perform method inlining across code boundaries that are not visible in source code, which means that it could elide an entire alternate branch from compilation if it determines that only one branch is taken in practice.

Comment: @JBNizet There is a measurable difference in performance.

Comment: By the way, if you’re going the road of such microoptimizations, you would reduce the branches even further, `for(int n: numbers) odds += Test.isOdd_A(n);`…

Comment: @joel That generates a compare instruction and the retrieval of a bit flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, 10% is not a speed difference that is worth any effort.

Note that explicit conversions to zero or one only happen when there is an explicit assignment to `boolean` (which includes `return` statements of methods declared to return `boolean`). When the expression is part of a conditional or a compound `boolean` expression, this will not happen, e.g.

```
static boolean isOddAndShort(int i) {
    return (i&1)!=0 && (i>>>16)==0;
}
```

compiles to

```
static boolean isOddAndShort(int);
descriptor: (I)Z
flags: ACC_STATIC
Code:
  stack=2, locals=1, args_size=1
     0: iload_0
     1: iconst_1
     2: iand
     3: ifeq          17
     6: iload_0
     7: bipush        16
     9: iushr
    10: ifne          17
    13: iconst_1
    14: goto          18
    17: iconst_0
    18: ireturn
```

As you see, the two expressions are not converted to *zero or one* before the `and` operation, only the final result.

Likewise

```
static void evenOrOdd(int i) {
    System.out.println((i&1)!=0? "odd": "even");
}
```

compiles to

```
static void evenOrOdd(int);
descriptor: (I)V
flags: ACC_STATIC
Code:
  stack=3, locals=1, args_size=1
     0: getstatic     #2        // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
     3: iload_0
     4: iconst_1
     5: iand
     6: ifeq          14
     9: ldc           #3        // String odd
    11: goto          16
    14: ldc           #4        // String even
    16: invokevirtual #5        // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    19: return
```

not bearing any conversion to *zero or one*.

(Note that comparing with zero here utilizes the knowledge about `i&1` returning zero or one better than comparing with one).

---

So when we’re talking about, e.g. 0.01% of an actual application code (or even less) and assume a 10% speedup of that particular code, we can expect an overall speed improvement of 0.001% (or even less).

---

Still, just for fun or as a small code compression feature (maybe as part of a more general code compression or byte code obfuscation), here, an ASM based solution:

To make the transformation easier, we define a place-holder method, `i2b` performing an `int` to `boolean` transformation and invoke it at the intended place(s). The transformator simply removes both, the method declaration and its invocations:

```
public class Example {
    private static boolean i2b(int i) {
        return i!=0;
    }
    public static boolean isOdd(int i) {
        return i2b(i&1);
    }
    public static void run() {
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
            System.out.println(i+": "+(isOdd(i)? "odd": "even"));
    }
}
```

```
public class Int2Bool {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String clName = Example.class.getName();
        ClassReader cr = new ClassReader(clName);
        ClassWriter cw = new ClassWriter(cr, 0);
        cr.accept(new ClassVisitor(Opcodes.ASM5, cw) {
            @Override
            public MethodVisitor visitMethod(int access, String name, String desc, String signature, String[] exceptions) {
                if(name.equals("i2b") && desc.equals("(I)Z")) return null;
                return new MethodVisitor(Opcodes.ASM5, super.visitMethod(access, name, desc, signature, exceptions)) {
                    @Override
                    public void visitMethodInsn(int opcode, String owner, String name, String desc, boolean itf) {
                        if(opcode == Opcodes.INVOKESTATIC && name.equals("i2b") &&  desc.equals("(I)Z"))
                            return;
                        super.visitMethodInsn(opcode, owner, name, desc, itf);
                    }
                };
            }
        }, 0);
        byte[] code = cw.toByteArray();
        if(writeBack(clName, code))
            Example.run();
        else
            runDynamically(clName, code);
    }
    private static boolean writeBack(String clName, byte[] code) {
        URL u = Int2Bool.class.getResource("/"+clName.replace('.', '/')+".class");
        if(u==null || !u.getProtocol().equals("file")) return false;
        try {
            Files.write(Paths.get(u.toURI()), code, StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING);
            return true;
        } catch(IOException|URISyntaxException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }

    private static void runDynamically(String clName, byte[] code) {
        // example run
        Class<?> rtClass = new ClassLoader() {
            Class<?> get() { return defineClass(clName, code, 0, code.length); }
        }.get();
        try {
            rtClass.getMethod("run").invoke(null);
        } catch (ReflectiveOperationException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The transformed method looks like

```
public static boolean isOdd(int);
descriptor: (I)Z
flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_STATIC
Code:
  stack=2, locals=1, args_size=1
     0: iload_0
     1: iconst_1
     2: iand
     3: ireturn
```

and works without problems. But as said, that’s just as an exercise, not of much practical worth.

Comment: I find 10% to be quite significant. This could be the difference between a battery lasting 2 hours, or 1 hour 48 minutes. If the operation actually takes a noticeable amount of time, then another 12 minutes is wasted waiting for output to appear.

Comment: @Cppplus1 not in software. You may get 10% difference just when you run the same software another time. If you read the *whole* answer, you’ve noticed that I referred to the particular tested operation that likely makes 0.01% of your actual application code, so saving 10% of it saves you 0.001% of the overall execution time. In other words, you managed to let your battery run 2 hours instead of 1:48, when you need energy for a year…

Comment: @Holger You are assuming that this hasn't been identified as a hot path already.  As I stated in the question this is a simplified example to illustrate the issue.  It demonstrates that avoiding the branch does make a noticeable difference.  If this method is used in something low-level like Integer.parse(String) or processing an image, it can have an impact relative to the volume of data that is processed. Context matters.

Comment: Your benchmark merely consists of that operation. For any real life code, the fraction will be *less* than that. As always with microbenchmarks. They tell you the maximum impact you could ever achieve. Anyway, I provided the code transformation tool. You can try your luck with real life code…

Comment: @Holger I appreciated the code.  It was an interesting exercise, but ultimately I abandoned the idea.  Still as you mentioned, it might be something to include in an obfuscator.